# Adding .tar file directory to JTree

Tags: java, tar, jtree

I have a JTree and I am adding directories and files to the JTree with no problem. Now one of the files I am adding is a `.tar` file, I can add the `.tar` file to the `JTree`

I no you can unzip the `.tar` file using `GZIPInputStream` as follows

```
InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

But is there a way of expanding this `.tar` file in the `JTree` to see all the sub directories in the `JTree` using this code when adding the `.tar` file to the JTree?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You will have to rely on a 3rd party library to extract the information about the tar's contents in order to populate your JTree. Good candidates include:

- [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/)
- [JTar](http://code.google.com/p/jtar/)
- [Java Tar](http://www.trustice.com/java/tar/)

Answer (score 0):

Shameless self-plug: The [TrueZIP](http://truezip.java.net/index.html) VFS has a TFileTree class. This class is a JTree for displaying (virtual) directory trees, including TAR files.

Here's the class Javadoc: http://truezip.java.net/truezip-file/apidocs/de/schlichtherle/truezip/file/swing/TFileTree.html

And here's how to get started with TrueZIP: http://truezip.java.net/kick-start/index.html

You should read the latter first - it will help you understand the few basics. Don't worry, it's really simple.